# Vector layer won't move as window resizes in Chrome

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I have a GeoJSON layer that I am treating as a javascript object in my openlayers map. When I use IE or Firefox, everything works fine. However, in Chrome, as I resize the window, the GeoJSON layer is not moving with the background wms.It stays static and becomes displaced from the wms. Even when I click around the map, it stays in its incorrect placement. Any ideas why Chrome is doing this? I guess I could redraw the layer everytime the window is changed. But that seems too drastic for this problem with this browser. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Any errors or warning in the chrome console?

Comment: You may be better off asking this on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

If this is with Chrome 18 this is a known issue. See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/392.

Comment: erilem is right, but don't despair can fix by applying the following patch (WFM): https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/467/files